# Mutually exclusive video output between laptop and external monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

### Problem

My laptop's main display and external monitor are not usable simultaneously. Depending on which drivers I use, either the laptop's screen is blank or the external monitor isn't connected or usable.

### Details

The laptop is an HP Omen with a 10th generation i7 and an Nvidia GeForce graphics card, and the monitor is a 27" AOC monitor. I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on it today. I'm connecting the laptop to the monitor via a HDMI cord.

### What I've tried

Initially, the laptop's screen was working correctly but the monitor was not connecting. To fix this, I switched from the X.org Nouveau display driver to the Nvidia 460 driver (or the 465 -- same behavior). Once I made this change and rebooted, the external monitor connected but the laptop's display was blank after showing the Omen logo while booting.

The `xrandr -q` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00
   1680x1050     59.95
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1280x960      60.00
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       59.94
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93
DP-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.01 + 300.18
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The `lspci -vv` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88c8
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 121
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: 73000000-740fffff [size=17M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000004000000000-0000004201ffffff [size=8224M]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA+ VGA16+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88c8
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at 423211f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88c8
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 129
    Region 0: Memory at 4232100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88c8
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Region 0: Memory at 4232118000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]
    Region 2: Memory at 423211e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
    DeviceName: Intel Wireless LAN + BT
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0074
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at 4232114000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88c8
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at 4202000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88c8
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at 4202001000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88c8
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 163
    Region 0: Memory at 423211b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at 74400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Region 1: Memory at 74403000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Region 2: I/O ports at 5050 [size=8]
    Region 3: I/O ports at 5040 [size=4]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 5020 [size=32]
    Region 5: Memory at 74402000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=3a, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00006000-00007fff [size=8K]
    Memory behind bridge: 5c000000-720fffff [size=353M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000004210000000-0000004231ffffff [size=544M]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- VGA16+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1b.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=3b, subordinate=3b, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: 74300000-743fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- VGA16+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b5 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 124
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=3c, subordinate=3c, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: 74200000-742fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- VGA16+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b7 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin D routed to IRQ 125
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=3d, subordinate=3d, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: 74100000-741fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- VGA16+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake LPC Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88c8
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88c8
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 178
    Region 0: Memory at 4232110000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Region 4: Memory at 4232000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88c8
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at 423211a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Region 4: I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88c8
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Region 0: Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 24dd (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: NVIDIA Graphics Device
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88c8
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 179
    Region 0: Memory at 73000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 1: Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8G]
    Region 3: Memory at 4200000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Region 5: I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 228b (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88c8
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at 74080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Physical Slot: 20
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 128 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=02, secondary=03, subordinate=3a, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00006000-00006fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: 5c000000-720fffff [size=353M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000004210000000-0000004231ffffff [size=544M]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- VGA16+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 128 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 126
    Bus: primary=03, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: 72000000-720fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- VGA16+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 128 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 127
    Bus: primary=03, secondary=05, subordinate=39, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00006000-00006fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: 5c000000-71efffff [size=351M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000004210000000-0000004231ffffff [size=544M]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- VGA16+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 128 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 128
    Bus: primary=03, secondary=3a, subordinate=3a, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: 71f00000-71ffffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- VGA16+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

04:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 128 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at 72000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Region 1: Memory at 72040000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
    Kernel modules: thunderbolt

3a:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 149
    Region 0: Memory at 71f00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

3b:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation Device 011a (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation Device 0001
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at 74300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme

3c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at 74204000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 4: Memory at 74200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

3d:00.0 SD Host controller: Genesys Logic, Inc GL9750 SD Host Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 01)
    DeviceName: Genesys Logic PCIE CardReader
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GL9750 SD Host Controller
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 148
    Region 0: Memory at 74100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
```

Comment: Hi @alex. Do you have multi monitor enabled in bios?

Comment: @jpbrain The BIOS doesn't appear to have an option related to this (from what I saw). I went through both the F2 and F10 BIOS settings and didn't see anything relating to this.

Comment: Look for IGD configuration. something like that. Your machine actually has 2 graphic cards (and thunderbolt can also be used for docking stations). The one internal of the CPU and the NVIDIA and thunderbolt. I have a similar configuration.

Comment: I can't find that setting in my BIOS. It seems like the HP BIOS is not particularly customizable (there are some forum posts elsewhere that talk about this).

With this in mind, are there programmatic ways to set these configurations in the BIOS?

Comment: Alright, I was able to fix the problem this morning! Will include the steps in an edit above.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by following the steps below.

First I checked to see what the recommended driver was with `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`, which provided the output:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000024DDsv0000103Csd000088C8bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - third-party non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-465 - third-party non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Given this output, the `nvidia-driver-460` was indicated as the correct driver to use. On another thread, people mentioned that Nvidia PRIME needed to be enabled to utilize the setup that I desired. What I did next was to run the command `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-460 nvidia-prime`. After this, I rebooted the machine and both displays were correctly recognized and things are working well now.